# function overloading unsolved example

Tags: java, overloading

```
public class Roshni {

    void sum(int i, int j) {
        System.out.println("inside 1st i = " + i);
    }
    void sum(short i, int j) {
        System.out.println("inside 2nd i = " + i);
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        Roshni r = new Roshni();
        r.sum(5, 5);
    }
}
```

now my question is why sum(int i,int j) is being called even if the first command line parameter 5 comes under the range of short whereas while i am typecasting like this r.sum(Short(5),5); then it is calling sum(short i,int j)

Comment: Please take the time to format your code when you ask a question - it would be much more readable if it were indented. Additionally, the example would be simpler without the second parameter, and if `sum` were a `static `method.

Comment: thanks John , will take care

Comment: @user4188607 - Thanks *Jon* :P

Comment: may i know why you suggested keeping  sum method as static Jon

Comment: There is no need for it to be non-static, as there is no state being used, and you have not mentioned a requirement to override the method in a subclass. It just avoids the need to create a `Roshni`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In java literal integers are [implicitly considered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) as `int`s.

So unless you specify it to be a `short` (by casting for example), it's a call for `sum(int i,int j)` as far as compiler is concerned.

Comment: can any body tell if my first function is sum(double i,int j) and second is sum(short i,int j) keeping the command line arguement same the which one will be called

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a matter of overload resolution - your method with the `short` parameter isn't even applicable. Here's an example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void foo(short x) {        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        foo(5); // Error
    }
}
```

This gives a compile-time error:

```
Test.java:10: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short
        foo(5);
            ^
```

The type of the integer literal is `int`, and there's no normal implicit conversion from `int` to `short`. Now you *can* write:

```
short x = 5;
```

... because that's in an [*assignment context*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), where additional conversions are available:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

That doesn't apply to method arguments, however.

Once you've got a value of type `short`, *then* overload resolution would come into play:

```
short x = 5;
r.sum(x, 5);
```

Now both methods are applicable, and the compiler will pick the second one as the more specific one following the rules of [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

Answer (score 0):

If you specify two methods as

```
sum(double i,int j)
sum(short i,int j)
```

Now if you call `sum(12.12,4)` then `sum(double i,int j)` will be called. Its because the real values or decimal values are of double type in java. To call the `sum(short i,int j)` to need to additionally specify by type casting it to short.

```
sum(short(12.23),4)
```

This type casting to short will discard the higher order bits from 64 bit double value of 12.23 and pick only the last 16 bits as a short value.